# Can i use flash animations as texture in blender?

Tags: animation, texturing, objects, import, video

I'm trying to use 2d animated face on a model. So how do I import or apply 2d animation on 3d models?

Comment: Does "flash" from the title referring to actual Adobe Flash file (.swf?) animation?

Comment: Yes you can use them, but not directly. They have to be converted (using external software) to a format that is compatible with blender.